# VHDL - Adding two std_logic_vectors, issue

Tags: digital-logic, fpga, vhdl

I'm having an issue when trying to add two `std_logic_vectors`.
The two vectors are `reg_A` and `reg_B`, they are both 8 bits wide and the result will be saved into `bit9_result`, which is a 9 bit `std_logic_vector`.
When adding the two numbers, I want them to be interpreted as unsigned.
After the addition, I want to check if an overflow has occurred, which I do by checking the MSB of the `bit9_result`.
Because `reg_A` and `reg_B` are 8 bits and I want the result to be 9 bits, I append the two registers with a leading 0.

```
bit9_result <= std_logic_vector(unsigned('0' & reg_A) + unsigned('0' & reg_B));
overflow <= bit9_result(8);
```

For `reg_A = 128`, `reg_B = 6`, the `bit9_result = 134` and `overflow = 0`.
However, when I enter
`reg_A = 5`, `reg_B = 128` (or any number for `reg_A` as long as `reg_B = 128`), I get overflow = 1, i.e. the MSB of `bit9_result` is 1.

Any ideas why it would work one way around but not the other? I've been stuck here for the past 10 working hours and would appreciate some help!

```vhdl
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity CtrlReg is
   port ( clk        : in  std_logic;
          reset      : in  std_logic;
          RegCtrl    : in  std_logic_vector (1 downto 0);   
          input      : in  std_logic_vector (7 downto 0);   -- Switch inputs
          A          : out std_logic_vector (7 downto 0);   -- Input A
          B          : out std_logic_vector (7 downto 0)   -- Input B
        );
end CtrlReg ;
architecture behavioral of CtrlReg is

signal reg_A, reg_B : std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
signal next_reg_A, next_reg_B : std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
begin
    registers: process(clk, reset)
    begin
        if rising_edge(clk) then
            if reset = '1' then
                A <= (others => '0');
                B <= (others => '0');
            else
                reg_A <= next_reg_A;
                reg_B <= next_reg_B;
            end if;
        end if;
    end process;
    
    comb: process(RegCtrl, input, reg_A, reg_B)
    begin

        next_reg_A <= reg_A;
        next_reg_B <= reg_B;

        if RegCtrl = "01" then
            next_reg_A <= input;
        elsif RegCtrl = "10" then
            next_reg_B <= input;
        end if;
    end process;
end behavioral;
```

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;
use work.ALU_components_pack.all;

entity ALU is
   port ( A          : in  std_logic_vector (7 downto 0);   -- Input A
          B          : in  std_logic_vector (7 downto 0);   -- Input B
          FN         : in  std_logic_vector (3 downto 0);  
          result       : out std_logic_vector (7 downto 0);   -- ALU output (unsigned)
           overflow   : out std_logic;                       -- '1' if overflow, else '0'
           sign       : out std_logic                        -- '1' if result is negative, else '0'
        );
end ALU;

architecture behavioral of ALU is

signal reg_A, reg_B : std_logic_vector(7 downto 0) := (others => '0');

constant B_TEST : std_logic_vector(7 downto 0) := "10000000";

-- Overflow
signal bit9_result : std_logic_vector(8 downto 0) := (others => '0');

begin

   process ( FN, A, B, bit9_result, mod3_result, reg_A, reg_B)
   begin
        overflow <= '0';
        result <= (others => '0');
        sign <= '0';
        bit9_result <= "000000000"
        reg_A <= A;
        reg_B <= B;
      
      case FN is
         when "0000" =>
            -- state_readA, display value
            result <= reg_A;
         when "0001" =>
            -- state_readB, display value
            result <= reg_B;
         when "0010" =>
            -- unsigned A + B
             bit9_result <= std_logic_vector(unsigned('0' & A) + unsigned('0' & reg_B));
            --bit9_result <= std_logic_vector(unsigned('0' & A) + unsigned('0' & B_TEST));

            overflow <= bit9_result(8);
            result <= bit9_result(7 downto 0);
        when others =>
        end case
    end process;
end behavioral;
```

```vhdl
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity ALU_ctrl is
   port ( clk     : in  std_logic;
          reset   : in  std_logic;
          enter   : in  std_logic;
          sign    : in  std_logic;
          FN      : out std_logic_vector (3 downto 0);   -- ALU functions
          RegCtrl : out std_logic_vector (1 downto 0)   -- Register update control bits
        );
end ALU_ctrl;

architecture behavioral of ALU_ctrl is

type state_type is ( state_read_A, state_read_B, 
                     state_unsigned_AplusB, state_unsigned_AminusB, state_unsigned_A_mod3,
                     state_signed_AplusB, state_signed_AminusB, state_signed_A_mod3
                     );

signal enter_edgeFound, next_enter_edgeFound : std_logic; 
signal sign_edgeFound, next_sign_edgeFound : std_logic; 
signal first_sampled_enter, first_sampled_sign : std_logic;

signal current_state, next_state : state_type;

signal next_RegCtrl : std_logic_vector(1 downto 0);
signal next_FN : std_logic_vector(3 downto 0) := "0000";

begin
   registers: process(clk, reset)
   begin
      -- Add if reset = ...
         if rising_edge(clk) then
            if reset = '1' then
                FN <= (others => '0');
                current_state <= state_read_A;
                RegCtrl <= (others => '0');
                enter_edgeFound <= '0';
                sign_edgeFound <= '0';
                
            else
               first_sampled_enter <= enter;
               first_sampled_sign <= sign;
               enter_edgeFound <= next_enter_edgeFound;
               sign_edgeFound <= next_sign_edgeFound;
               RegCtrl <= next_RegCtrl;
               FN <= next_FN;
               current_state <= next_state;
            end if;
         end if;

   end process;

   -- Detects whether or not button 'enter' and 'sign' has been released
   edgeDetect: process(enter, first_sampled_enter, first_sampled_sign, sign)
   begin
      next_enter_edgeFound <= '0';
      next_sign_edgeFound <= '0';
      if first_sampled_enter = '1' and enter = '0' then
         next_enter_edgeFound <= '1';
      end if;
      if first_sampled_sign = '1' and sign = '0' then
         next_sign_edgeFound <= '1';
      end if;
   end process;

   state_comb:process(current_state, enter_edgeFound, sign_edgeFound)
   begin
    next_RegCtrl <= "00";
    next_state <= current_state;
      case current_state is 
         when state_read_A             =>
            -- Read A when button is pressed
            next_FN <= "0000";
            next_RegCtrl <= "01";
            if enter_edgeFound = '1' then
               -- Go to read B
               next_state <= state_read_B;
            end if;

         when state_read_B             =>
            next_FN <= "0001";   
            next_RegCtrl <= "10";        
            if enter_edgeFound = '1' then
               -- Step into unsigned loop
               next_state <= state_unsigned_AplusB;
            end if;

         when state_unsigned_AplusB    =>
            next_FN <= "0010";
            if enter_edgeFound = '1' then
               -- Step through unsigned loop
               next_state <= state_unsigned_AminusB;
            end if;


      end case;
   end process;   

end behavioral;
```

In the `CtrlReg`, the input is stored in registers `A` and `B`. This is done by setting input on switches and sampling a button press. The signals from registers `A` and `B` are mapped to the ports with the same name on ALU.

Comment: Please post what they call "minimal reproducible example". From the snippets you are showing it is impossible to see the problem.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Edited the post, hopefully it's readable

Comment: Where do you use your `ALU` and `CtrlReg` components? Cause e.g. in the `CtrlReg` it seems like the outputs `A` and `B` are only initialized to zero but never assigned. So this component doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 1):

When you assign a signal (with <=), then the signal is updated after the process.
I suggest you assign a variable first or do the "overflow <= bit9_result(8);" outside the process.

Answer (score 1):

From the understanding of your requirements, you should be doing continuous assignment to `overflow`. i.e, outside the `process` as a concurrent statement inside `architecture`.

```
process ()

...

end process ;

overflow <= bit9_result (8) ;
```

Right now, you have a one cycle delay at `overflow`, which is giving you the wrong impression on simulation.